# how do I get_sidebar into a varaible?

Tags: sidebar

I want to get a sidebar and save it in a Variable, 
This is impossible with the get_sidebar function since it simply prints out 
the sidebar, is there another function that I can use?

Comment: What do you want to *do* with this variable?

Comment: I want to add widgets from a "page" content, so I'm trying to replace tags like %SIDEBAR_3% to the actual sidebar, so I'm using str_replace but I need a function that returns something

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You probably need to use [output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php), if I understand your question correctly.

Try something like this:

```
ob_start();
dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-id');
$sidebar = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

That will put the output of the sidebar into the variable $sidebar, which you can then process and return from your filter on the page content.

Comment: worked for me! thanks! had to save the entire footer html output in a transient. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `get_sidebar()` function is an *include* function, used to include `sidebar.php`.

The function I think you're after is `dynamic_sidebar()` ([Codex ref](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar)), assuming you know the ID of the dynamic sidebar you want to use.