# How do I store get_sidebar in a varaible?

Tags: sidebar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how do I get_sidebar into a varaible?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22943/how-do-i-get-sidebar-into-a-varaible)

I found [how do I get_sidebar into a varaible?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22943/how-do-i-get-sidebar-into-a-varaible) but the goal was different than mine, so the answers don't apply.

I want to get a sidebar and save it into a variable so that I can create an if/elseif statement that will print the correct sidebar depending on my conditional criteria.  For example, I currently have something like this...

```
if ( is_page(1) ) {
    $sidebar = get_sidebar('wine');
} elseif ( is_page(2) ) {
    $sidebar = get_sidebar('cheese');
} elseif ( is_page(3) ) {
    $sidebar = get_sidebar('whatever');
} else {
    $sidebar = get_sidebar('primary');
}
```

I'm not actually using **is_page** in my conditional statements and I am setting more than just the **$sidebar** variable, but you get the idea.  Further down in the code I want to do this...

```
echo $sidebar;
```

The sidebars I am working with are not all dynamic, but some are.  So, is there a function besides **get_sidebar()** that I can use?

---

UPDATE = ANSWER

Oh, why did I hit enter? The answer left by goldenapples on the question I linked to (above) did do exactly what I wanted. When I first read it I misunderstood what output buffering did, so I didn't think it applied. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

`get_sidebar()` just includes a template, so its as dynamic as the string you pass to it. If you want to capture output and store it all as a variable, use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) native to PHP.