# Dynamic sidebar rendered in another place than i would like

Tags: sidebar, register-sidebar

I'm trying include dynamic sidebar to Uncode Theme. I created child template, then I created all files and now I have a piece of code who shows content and sidebar area.

In `functions.php` I created dynamic sidebar:

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', function () {
    $args = array(
        'name'          => __( 'Sidebar Messages Single', 'uncode' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-messages-single', 
    'description'   => '',
        'class'         => 'dynamic-widget',
    'before_widget' => '<li id="dynamic-sidebar" class="widget">',
    'after_widget'  => '</li>',
    'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
    'after_title'   => '</h2>'
    ); 

    register_sidebar( $args );
});
```

Then in `single-portfolio.php` I'm trying include that sidebar.

```
$sidebar_widgets = is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-messages-single' ) ? dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-messages-single' ) : null;

$the_content = '<div class="row-container">
    <div class="row row-parent' . $row_classes . $limit_content_width . '">
        <div class="row-inner">
            ' . (($layout === 'sidebar_right') ? $main_content : '') . '
            <div class="col-lg-' . $sidebar_size . '">
                <div class="uncol style-' . $portfolio_style . $expand_col . $sidebar_padding . (($sidebar_fill === 'on' && $portfolio_bg_color !== '') ? '' : $sidebar_sticky) . '">
                    <div class="uncoltable' . (($sidebar_fill === 'on' && $portfolio_bg_color !== '') ? $sidebar_sticky : '') . '">
                        <div class="uncell' . $sidebar_inner_padding . '">
                            <div class="uncont">
                                <div>
                                    ' . $sidebar_widgets . '
                                </div>
                                ' . $footer_content . '
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            ' . (($layout === 'sidebar_left') ? $main_content : '') . '
        </div>
    </div>
</div>';
```

It seems to me everything is alright, but when I render page I get this result.

[image]
The place where sidebar should be render I get int (one). Whereas sidebar is rendered in another place.

At first I thought it is DOM manipulated via JavaScript, but when I debugged and disabled JS it worked the same.

Furthermore, when I added normal string to `<div>` beside variable `$sidebar_widget`. String rendered in correct place.

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: You can't put `dynamic_sidebar()` into a variable like that. That function echoes its results. Is there a particular reason you've built your template as a giant string?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is theme providers work (Uncode). I try to add function directly to string but I get the same result.

I want to avoid reconstruction all theme for only add sidebar.

Comment: actually @Jacob Peattie is completely right, you can't store `dynamic_sidebar` cannot be saved in a variable, because it always echoes out the widget, you have to add it directly within your markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't save `dynamic_sidebar` in a variable because it always echoes out the widget. the following should work.

```
<?php

echo '<div class="row-container">
<div class="row row-parent' . $row_classes . $limit_content_width . '">
    <div class="row-inner">';
     if(($layout === 'sidebar_right') && is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-messages-single' )) {
        dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-messages-single' );
     }
      echo '<div class="col-lg-' . $sidebar_size . '">
            <div class="uncol style-' . $portfolio_style . $expand_col . $sidebar_padding . (($sidebar_fill === 'on' && $portfolio_bg_color !== '') ? '' : $sidebar_sticky) . '">
                <div class="uncoltable' . (($sidebar_fill === 'on' && $portfolio_bg_color !== '') ? $sidebar_sticky : '') . '">
                    <div class="uncell' . $sidebar_inner_padding . '">
                        <div class="uncont">
                            <div>';
                                 if(is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-messages-single' )) {
                                     dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-messages-single' );
                                 }
                               echo '</div>
                            ' . $footer_content . '
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>';
         if(($layout === 'sidebar_left') && is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-messages-single' )) {
            dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-messages-single' );
         }
    echo '</div>
</div>
</div>';
```

Comment: Thank you. It is the correct way. But my theme provider processes `$the_content` and I can't show the result at this moment. I contact with them.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution for someone have to use variable**

Thanks to the topic [how do I get_sidebar into a varaible?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22943/how-do-i-get-sidebar-into-a-varaible)

I change my code into:

```
...
<div class="uncont">
ob_start();
if(is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-messages-single' )) {
    dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-messages-single' );
}
$the_content .= ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
</div>
...
```

I know that isn't it elegant solution, but if someone has to fast fix 3rd party theme (eg. Uncode) it is one of the ways.